# react-cognito and router v4: redirecting user to requested PrivateRoute after login

Tags: reactjs, redux, amazon-cognito, react-router-v4

I'm new at React+Redux+Router and I'm scratching my head over how to have the user forwarded to the PrivateRoute requested after successful login.

react-cognito fires `COGNITO_LOGIN` action and sets `cognito.state = "LOGGED_IN"` in the store at successful login. I know react-router stores the requested route in `location.state.from.pathname`, and I know that to redirect the BrowserRouter I can use `history.replace()`.

I just don't know where my code goes so that it executes after the react-cognito onSubmit login function asynchronously completes, given there's no callback provided by this package.

In my login form component I tried

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.cognito.state === 'LOGGED_IN') {
      // logged in, let's show redirect if any, or show home
      try {
        const { from } = this.props.location.state || {
          from: { pathname: "/" }
        };
        nextProps.history.replace(from);
      } catch (err) {
        nextProps.history.replace("/");
      }
    }
  }
```

...but it executed too early. I don't think something like this belongs in a reducer since these seem intended only to directly manipulate the store, but I could be way off there.

Is there some functionality within the react-router-redux package that may provide something helpful here?

Am I stuck without a callback? Is there no way to watch for the change of cognito.state?

Suggestions welcome.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of doing it with `react-router-v4` is to render a `<Redirect />` which will take care of redirection.

In your case:

```
render() {
    if (this.props.cognito.state === 'LOGGED_IN') {
        return (<Redirect to="/" />)
    }
    //...
}
```

This replaces the current location by default.

See [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) example for further information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `push` method in your action to dispatch an action which will redirect your app to desired location/route.

> action.js

```
import {push} from 'react-router-redux';

/*** write your API here and after success redirect your route ***/

.then(() => {
   dispatch(push(args.redirectRoute))
 })
```

Make sure you [configured](http://manojsinghnegi.com/blog/2017/09/03/Implementing-redux-and-react-router-v4-in-your-react-app/) your **React Router** with **Redux**.